# Vertical Slider Using touch only iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am developing an app in which I need to use vertical slider which is having particular range i.e it slide between 0 to 100 values etc.

I have tried but not getting proper solution

Comment: Your last three questions (I got bored after that) have all been "urgent". Please stop putting that on your questions, it is not relevant and is more likely to annoy people than encourage them to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Change the **transform** property of the **slider**.

Basically the **first parameter** is the **existing transformation matrix** of the slider, and the **second** is the n**umber of degrees (in radians)** that you want to rotate the slider.

```
 IBOutlet UISlider *slider;

slider.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(slider.transform, 270.0/180*M_PI);
```

Comment: Kind of standoffish to tell the OP to Accept your answer, don't you think? Especially while using terrible english.